# sharing common components in a helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a Kubernetes cluster in which I would like to deploy various company dependent pods and services.
All of them need some common components (e.g. ingress, traefik, postgres).
Therefore I had designed a chart structure:

```
- myproject
  charts
    - ingress
    - traefik
    - postgres
  templates
    - svc1
    - pod1
    - svc2
    - pod2
```

My idea was to control the company-dependent pods/services via environment variables and do deployments like this:
`helm install --set env="dev" --set company="cat" ./myproject`
or
`helm install --set env="prod" --set company="dog" ./myproject`

svc1, svc2, ... read the env values.

Anyway, this construct doesn't work. I get an error that some common component already exists.
I understand this. 
I think one way to avoid the problem would be to create a separate chart for ingress, traefik etc. and generate it first.
But I have the feeling that this is not right way. What would be a good solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are all the charts developed by you? or are you using 3rd party charts?
Depending on how you are using the charts this might alter the solution.

Have you tried using something related to DRY? this [article](https://medium.com/faun/dry-helm-charts-for-micro-services-db3a1d6ecb80) is very helpful for using DRY in helm.

Also, would be very helpful if you shared the error that is happening.

Comment: Thank you for the DRY-article. It is interesting. However for my problem I did in a first step the following thing:
Traefik is the only service that is global and company/environment independant.
So I have a chart separate for traefik and another chart for all the company/environment dependant services. 
And I use different customer configured value-files for different companies/environments(start with 'helm install -f company1-dev.yaml ./services').

Comment: Understood, about you error **I get an error that some common component already exists.** it probably is because of the naming pattern you are using for the charts and multiple charts are creating a resource with the same name.
Try adding something specific about companies/environments in the name of the resources.